# "Double-click Touch ID to pay" doesn't work on MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, touch-id, sonoma, apple-pay

At some point during the macOS Sonoma release, my Apple Pay dialog in Safari began saying "Double-click Touch ID to pay" instead of the usual process of simply touching the Touch ID sensor to approve the payment.

Trying to do this would immediately lock and unlock the screen instead of process the payment. If I'm lucky, I might be prompted for my login password instead.

How can I make payments with Apple Pay in Safari on my MacBook running Sonoma?

Comment: Any idea what "Double-click Touch ID to pay" actually means? I have no idea based on the icon and tapping the Touch ID / power button twice puts my laptop to sleep. Terrible UX from Apple here.

Comment: @JamesMcMahon Nope, none.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to restore the previous behavior by going to "System Settings", "Touch ID & Password", turning off "Use Touch ID for Apple Pay", then turning it back on again.

[image: The System Settings dialog for Touch ID & Password, with the "Use Touch ID for Apple Pay" item highlighted.]

Once this process was complete, the next payment I made once again simply prompted me to touch the Touch ID sensor, no clicks required.

Comment: Had the same issue; toggling this setting fixed it for me